# Split standalone.xml Configuration file

Tags: jboss7.x

Is there a way to import another file into standalone.xml file, like for exemple `import` in Spring configuration files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If nothing else you can make use of external entities:

```
<!DOCTYPE domain [
  <!ENTITY section1 SYSTEM "section1.xml">
]>
```

and then use `&section1;` to include it at the appropriate place.

Comment: Could it make applications vulnerable to XXE attacks?